# Ubuntu 16.04.1 can't detect Android device

Tags: android, ubuntu

As the title says, I'm running Ubuntu (more specifically Xubuntu) and I'm trying to use my Android device to test my app in Android Studio.

Yes, I have developer mode turned on. Yes, I have USB debugging turned on. The USB configuration is set to MTP as well.

I've followed [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html), but no dice. I did everything it said, and still nothing.

Android Studio says there is no device connected via USB (it is) when I try to run the app; lsusb in the terminal doesn't seem to list my device (Samsung Galaxy S6); I installed libmtp9 and used the command mtp-detect, but it said no device was found.

When I tried to execute "adb devices" as it says in the instructions, the terminal would tell me something along the lines of "adb failed to ACK," "daemon thread failed." I can't remember exactly because I actually just did it again, and it said the thread was successful this time (out of nowhere) and everything ended without any error. However, when I went back into Android Studio, it still doesn't list my device.

Help would be greatly appreciated. If I can't get this to work, I'll have to resort to Windows 10 again.

Comment: try `adb kill-server && adb start-server`

Comment: Okay, so it was doing its thing for like a minute, then fed me: * server not running *. I just tried restarting Android Studio and running the application again. It still doesn't list my device.

Comment: "Setting up a device"  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html   should help

Comment: I linked to that in the post. I've followed all the instructions and got nowhere. It didn't help at all.

Comment: well .. cud also try swapping usb connectors on device to PC. I recall posts where that helped this typ issue  http://askubuntu.com/questions/463015/ubuntu-14-04-and-android-cant-see-phone-on-my-computer

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.